# Do I have to set width constraints a UILabel in a UITableviewcell

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I'm using autolayout for my cell . I need to add a label into this cell and how many lines does it has is determined by its content ， so I set "lines" to 0 . These are the constraints of the label.[constraints of the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFC3T.png)

The label doesn't add new lines even it can't wrap the text in it.

After I set the width <= 200.
[width<=200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOBar.png)

The label adds new lines as expected.

Comment: You can use preferredMaxLayoutWidth instead of width constraint

Comment: What would preferredMaxLayoutWidth affect？Should I calculate it accurately

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a trailing constraint instead of the width constraint. If you pin your `UILabel` to all four sides it automatically knows its width:

[image]